# custom directive highlight button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to write a custom directive that display button as the day in the week

as demonstrated in the picture below.

[image]

This is what i have so far and have trouble binding the ng-model back the directive.

Initially, the button is white and depending on the model currently passed as an array

```
$scope.selectedDays = ["mon", "wed"];
```

For the above example Monday and Wed should be highlighted in grey. all others should be white.

Any idea?

```
app.directive('daysDirective', function ($compile) {

    var days = [
        { key: "sun", display: "S"},
        { key: "mon", display: "M"},
        { key: "tue", display: "T"},
        { key: "wed", display: "W"},
        { key: "thurs", display: "T"},
        { key: "fri", display: "F"},
        { key: "sat", display: "S"}
    ];

    //var template =
    //     '  <div class="input-group">'+
    //     '      <button ng-repeat="day in days track by $index" ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': day.selected, \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !day.selected}">{{ day.display }}</button>' +
    //     '  </div>';

    var template =
         '  <div class="input-group">'+
         '      <button ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': day.selected, \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !day.selected}">S</button>' +
         '      <button ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': day.selected, \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !day.selected}">M</button>' +
         '      <button ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': day.selected, \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !day.selected}">T</button>' +
         '      <button ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': day.selected, \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !day.selected}">W</button>' +
         '      <button ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': day.selected, \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !day.selected}">T</button>' +
         '      <button ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': day.selected, \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !day.selected}">F</button>' +
         '      <button ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': day.selected, \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !day.selected}">S</button>' +
         '  </div>';

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        element.html(template).show();
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: linker,
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.days = days;
            var model = $scope.model;

            //$scope.selected = model[]
        }]
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your directive by using the template property

```
app.directive('daysDirective', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelController) {
            //not required, unless you are actually going to use ngModelController
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '  <div class="input-group">' +
                  '      <button ng-repeat="(key, day) in days track by $index"  ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': day.selected, \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !day.selected}">{{ day.display }}</button>' +
                  '  </div>',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            //this needs to move into your controller, because otherwise all instances will share the same instance of days, causing them to interfere with each other
            $scope.days = {
                sun: { display: "S"},
                mon: { display: "M"},
                tue: { display: "T"},
                wed: {display: "W"},
                thurs: { display: "T"},
                fri: { display: "F"},
                sat: { display: "S"}
            };


            $scope.$watchCollection('model', function(){
                //clear the selected attribute 
                for(var i in $scope.days) {
                    $scope.days[i].selected = false;
                }

                for(var i in $scope.model) {
                   $scope.days[$scope.model[i]].selected = true;
                }


            });
        }]
    };

});
```

You can avoid the complexity of the watch altogether:

```
app.directive('daysDirective', function () {

             var days = {
                sun: { display: "S"},
                mon: { display: "M"},
                tue: { display: "T"},
                wed: {display: "W"},
                thurs: { display: "T"},
                fri: { display: "F"},
                sat: { display: "S"}
            };
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelController) {
            //not required, unless you are actually going to use ngModelController
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '  <div class="input-group">' +
                  '      <button ng-click="Toggle(day)" ng-repeat="day in days track by $index"  ng-class="{\'btn btn-sm btn-white\': isSelected(day.key), \'btn btn-sm btn-grey\': !isSelected(day.key)}">{{ day.display }}</button>' +
                  '  </div>',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.days = days;
            $scope.isSelected = function(day) {
                return $scope.model.indexOf(day) > -1

            }

            $scope.Toggle = function(day) {
                var idx = $scope.model.indexOf(day.key);
                if(idx > -1)
                    $scope.model.splice(idx, 1);
                }
                else {
                    $scope.model.push(day.key);
                }

            }


        }]
    };

});
```

Comment: Thanks Joe! the model needs to be updated too with the array of user selected days. How can you do it without using watch on model?

Comment: You've already done it.  Just update the array you are passing into the directive "model" parameter.  It'll work.

Comment: probably i have not rephrase correctly, i want $scope.selectedDays to be updated with user selected day. if user selects mon, tue,wed then scope.selectedDays = ["mon", "tue","wed"]; I am storing scope.selectedDays.

Comment: also the ng-repeat appear to be sorting in alphabetically order. How can i turn that off?

Comment: I edited the second solution to revert back to using an array for days (solves ordering problem), and added a toggle function that should solve the other issue.

Comment: The splice part does not work properly where you unselect the day

Comment: It is interesting when we need ngModelController in the link function? I notice the ng-model can be updated using $scope.model passed in

Comment: You'd use ngModelController if you were doing validation other types of form-like operations on your data.